# Maximum Number of Edge Disjoint Paths of Length k in DAG

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, optimization, approximation

Is it known if the problem of finding the maximum number of edge disjoint paths of length k in a DAG is in P? Or has it shown to be NP-Complete? If so, are there approximation algorithms known for it?

I'd be interested if there are FPT algorithms as well, or even run time in O(n^k).

I'm aware that if there are no length restrictions and we're given two target nodes this is in P, using network flow.

It has some connections to Digraph Ordering (see [Kenkre's recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00662)) in terms of establishing upper bounds.

One way to begin to approach the problem is to define an LP which maximizes the sum of 0-1 path variables, and ensures no two paths given value 1 overlap. (If we're a little careful we can do this with polynomially many constraints) However, we have to round our solution to get anywhere.

Comment: Have you researched this? What have you found so far? We're not librarians, we're here to assist if you can't get your algorithm to work.

Comment: @adam-b I haven't been able to find anything on this problem -- I was hoping someone else knew about it (maybe it has a name I'm not aware of, for example). I added a few notes in the main post in case they're helpful.

Comment: I'd actually take this one straight to cstheory -- more expertise of the sort needed there than on cs. If this is a practical problem, though, you might do well by trying to solve the integer program with standardish techniques.

Comment: @Zach-Langley Thanks for the response! I'm not sure I quite see. Couldn't we take the same edge more than once in different copies of the graph? For example, for k=3 and a line graph A->B->C->D, we could take the paths A->B->C, as well as B->C->D, since these involve disjoint edges in the copied graphs (however, clearly these paths aren't edge disjoint). Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: The case $k=1$ can be solved in polynomial time, using a non-trivial algorithm. (It's just maximum matching.)

Comment: @Yuval-Filmus Ah, yeah I think I should have specified the paths must be edge-disjoint, not vertex-disjoint. Depending on how we value k (in my comment above, I implied that k is the number of nodes in the path) -- I'm assuming you imply that the path uses 1 edge. In this case, the algorithm does seem trivial: simply choose every edge. If we use k=2 (in terms of number of edges), it doesn't appear to be maximum matching. If we were to require vertex disjoint paths, I agree though -- thanks for prompting that clarification!

Comment: Can one of those paths use the same vertex more than once? ​ ​

Comment: Yes -- the paths only need to be edge disjoint, not vertex disjoint.

Comment: Research "kidney exchanges"; they are about vertex disjoint paths of length $\le k$ in a general graph, rather than edge disjoint paths of length $=k$ in a DAG, but they're loosely related, and maybe that can help you find papers that might discuss you rproblem.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks, I'll check that out! I'll let you know if this yields anything. It's tricky to generalize results from general digraphs since finding long paths in these cases is already NP-Hard, but hopefully there's some connection here.